# MySQL single auto increment for two tables without duplication a better solution

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables(innodb) in MYSQL data base both share a similar column the `account_no` column i want to keep both columns as integers and still keep both free from collusion when inserting data only.

there are 13 instances of this same question on stackoverflow i have read all. but in all, the recommended solutions where:

1) using GUID :this is good but am trying to keep the numbers short and easy for the users to remember.

2) using sequence :i do not fully understand how to do this but am thinking it involves making a third table that has an auto_increment and getting my values for the the two major tables from it.

3) using IDENTITY (1, 10) [1,11,21...] for the first table and the second using IDENTITY (2, 10) [2,12,22...] this works fine but in the long term might not be such a good idea.

4) using php function uniqid(,TRUE) :not going to work its not completely collision free and the columns in my case have to be integers.

5) using php function mt_rand(0,10): might work but i still have to check for collisions before inserting data.

if there is no smarter way to archive my goal i would stick with using the adjusted IDENTITY (1, 10) and (2, 10).

i know this question is a bit dumb seeing all the options i have available but the most recent answer on a similar topic was in 2012 there might have been some improvements in the MYSQL system that i do not know about yet.

also am using php language to insert the data thanks.

Comment: i apologize if i did not phrase my question well still new to stackoverflow this is my 4th question and have always been down voted for not explaining my problem well and not conducting enough research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you are saying that you have two flavors of an entity.  My first recommendation is to try to put them in a single table.  There are three methods:

- If most columns overlap, just put all the columns in a single table (`accounts`).
- If one entity has more columns, put the common columns in one table and have a second table for the wider entity.
- If only some columns overlap, put those in a single table and have a separate table for each subentity.

Let met assume the third situation for the moment.

You want to define something like:

```
create table accounts (
    AccountId int auto_increment primary key,
    . . .  -- you can still have common columns here
);

create table subaccount_1 (
    AccountId int primary key,
    constraint foreign key (AccountId) references accounts(AccountId),
    . . .
);

create table subaccount_2 (
    AccountId int primary key,
    constraint foreign key (AccountId) references accounts(AccountId),
    . . .
);
```

Then, you want an insert trigger on each sub-account table.  This trigger does the following on insert:

- inserts a row into `accounts`
- captures the new `accountId`
- uses that for the insert into the subaccount table

You probably also want something on `accounts` that prevents inserts into that table, except through the subaccount tables.

Comment: okay i understand your solution i insert data to the first table which does nothing else other than hold the inserted data generating a unique ID for the `account` column through the use of auto_increment and checks for collusion through the use of primary_key

Comment: then i issue a trigger to insert the data to either of the two other tables on successful insert of data on the first table am i right?

Comment: also one last question what would be the best way to issue a trigger for this case? thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that triggers will work for you. As Gordon indicates above, you must insert a row into 'accounts' capturing the accountId, then insert a corresponding row into the pertinent sub-account table. Create a method for each of these cases in the DAO's for the various sub-accounts.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff i finally got the power to up vote so once again a super thank you to you :)

Answer (score 1):

A big thank you to Gordon Linoff for his answer i want to fully explain how i solved the problem using his answer to help others understand better.

```
original tables:
Table A (account_no, fist_name, last_name)
Table B (account_no, likes, dislikes)
```

problem: need `account_no` to auto_increment across both tables and be unique across both tables and remain a medium positive integer (see original question).

i had to make an extra `Table_C` to which will hold all the inserted data at first, auto_increment it and checks for collisions through the use of primary_key

```
CREATE TABLE Table_C (
account_no int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
fist_name varchar(50),
last_name varchar(50),
likes varchar(50),
dislikes varchar(50),
which_table varchar(1),
PRIMARY KEY (account_no)
);
```

Then i changed MySQL INSERT statement to insert to `Table_C` and added an extra column `which_table` to say which table the data being inserted belong to and Table_C on insert of data performs auto_increment and checks collision then reinsert the data to the desired table through the use of triggers like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `sort_tables` AFTER INSERT ON `Table_C` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF new.which_table = 'A' THEN
INSERT INTO Table_A 
VALUES (new.acc_no, new.first_name, new.last_name); 

ELSEIF new.which_table = 'B' THEN
INSERT INTO Table_B 
VALUES (new.acc_no, new.likes, new.dislikes);

END IF;
END
```